# How to write a survey paper in mathematics?

Tags: mathematics, literature-review, review-articles

I want to write a survey article on one research topic, and on this topic, not much research has been done. Very few articles are available in the literature. To me, it seems an interesting topic to be explored by the researchers. For the same, I want to write a literature review survey.

I just want to know in which direction I shall move first. Is there any good way to handle the survey process in a good efficient and quick way? Is there any advantage to writing such a paper?

Comment: Hmm, I'm a bit confused: if there are only very few results available in this topic yet, then what is there to survey?

Comment: In mathematics true survey papers, meaning something helpful to researchers in the subject and not something primarily designed to provide an overview of the subject for someone wanting to begin working in it, are **nearly always** written by someone **extremely knowledgeable** about the subject (i.e. not a student or an early career researcher) due to the possible diverse connections among many highly technical topics, and the highly scattered nature of the literature, and the technical expertise needed to recognize and organize many different approaches often found in a developing subject.

Comment: @JochenGlueck I mean in a year, not many articles are published on this topic. Although there are articles closely related to this.

Comment: Don't you need to do the literature search before you can write a survey? You don't have to write up the search first, though.

Comment: "_not much research has been done. Very few articles are available in the literature._" Then, what to survey?

Answer (score 9):

> I want to write a survey article on one research topic, and on this topic, not much research has been done. Very few articles are available in the literature.

As a mathematician, I cannot make sense of what you are saying here. Survey papers are only written about topics on which there is already an extensive literature. Summarizing and surveying that literature is literally the purpose of a survey paper (in mathematics at least).

> Is there any good way to handle the survey process in a good efficient and quick way?

It’s also difficult to understand what you mean here. My impression is that your mental image of what it means to write a survey paper differs significantly from mine.

> Is there any advantage to writing such a paper?

If you’re an early career researcher, then no, this will almost certainly not help you professionally.

Comment: There have been useful *expository* papers that take one or a small number of highly technical, difficult papers and explain their main results in more detail, perhaps adding a number of useful examples.  Sometimes they are written by early career researchers and have established these researchers a reputation for being able to explain certain technical results to other people who might then use them in ways beyond the original context.